# Diferencia entre usar unidad en la interfaz o en la implementación

Tags: delphi

Diferencia entre usar unidad en la interfaz o en la implementación.

Voy a agregar una unidad a otra en Delphi (Alt + F11), me preguntá si lo agrego en la interfaz o en la implementación, noto que en ambas opciones funciona.

¿Cúal es la diferencia de agregarla en la interfaz o en la implementación?

**Código:**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, uDataModule;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

**Vs**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses uDataModule;

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que un paralelismo podría ser el de definir una variable `Global` o `Privada`. Segúramente si la defines de las 2 formas, el programa funcionará, pero por visibilidad y encapsulamiento sería más correcto definirla con el ámbito menor, es decir, es mejor inicialmente (y salvo que necesites otra cosa) definirla como `Privada`.

En este caso pasa algo similar. Si la unit que necesitas sólo se utiliza en la `Implementación`, sería más correcto añadir esa unit a la parte de `implementación`. Si se usa también en la parte de `Interface`, no tendrás otro remedio que definirla en la parte de `Interface` (ámbito más amplio).

El hecho de definir todas las units en la parte de `Interface`, hará que el código funcione siempre, pero puede traer problemas a posteriori [con "referencias circulares"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Programs_and_Units#Circular_Unit_References).

[Aquí está la explicación del error](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/F2047_Circular_unit_reference_to_'%25s'_(Delphi)).